# unable to remove some codes from robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I have a weird problem. I am able to update my `robots.txt` however for some reason, whenever I click on www.mysite.com/robots.txt, the following code would always be at the end:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Crawl-delay: 10
```

I could change any other stuff and it would show instantly. But this code at the end just appears from nowhere! I don't see it when I download the `robots.txt` from my file manager.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to temporary rename your `robots.txt` on the server - if you still can access it after verifying that the file is definitely not preset in your webroot anymore your `robots.txt` seems to be auto-updated/generate from either

- a CDN (I've seen this issue with some improper maxCDN setup recently)
- a third party module inside your Magento installation (i.e. something like this https://github.com/guidance/Guidance_Simplepage)
- a custom php script not integrated into Magento directly - in this case you may find a redirect inside your `.htaccess` (in case you're hosting on an Apache server, or in your nginx-config - i.e. something like described here http://stuartgeiger.com/posts/2014/05/robots-txt/)